# Javascript - text field submits to a popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, popup

I need to have this logic

( textfield ) (submit button)

Person enters a string of numbers/letters - if its right; a popup window happens showing a pdf. if its wrong validation happens and they are presented with an error message

I have gotten this to work as a DROP DOWN >> to >> PDF POPUP. But that wont work.

Can anyone help me with this -- spent way to make hours getting the drop to pop working and need to change directions.

note: needs to work in wordpress page + template.

```
<form style="float:right;">
<table width="369" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
 <td><select name="URL" style="font-size:20px;background:yellow;padding:9px 15px;-webkit-      border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #000000), to(#FFFFFF)); background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #000000 1px, #FFFFFF 25px);">
 <option value="">Select your number</option>
 <option value="123.pdf">123</option>
 <option value="456.pdf">456</option>
 </select></td>
 <td><p><input type="button" style="padding:9px 15px; background: #617798; border: 0; font-size: 14px; color: #FFFFFF;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;!important;"   value="Check Number #" onclick="if (this.form.URL.value) window.open(this.form.URL.value, '_blank','toolbar=0','width=30','height=20');" /><br /></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
​
```

Javascript:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    if ($('input[type=text]').val() == "some_pdf.pdf") {
        window.open("http://link_to_some_pdf.com/some_pdf.pdf");
    } else if ($('input[type=text]').val() == "some_other_pdf.pdf") {
        window.open("http://link_to_some_other_pdf.com/some_other_pdf.pdf");
    }  else {
        alert("Not a valid PDF! Try again!");
    }
});
```

​

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vu26C/

Comment: @user1608231 http://jsfiddle.net/GCv96/1/ you had a ? mark typo which messed it up, I also put google.com redirect so you can see where it might take you.

Comment: mash - awesome. working. More questions
1) how can i easily add more values like some_pdf.pdf?
2) Validation - how can i give/show an error if the wrong PDF is put in.

Comment: You might want to put those in a separate question...and accept Mash's answer.

Comment: @user1608231 Updated my answer with that info.

Comment: I cannot accept until 15 minutes goes by.

@mash - this is working at jsfiddle. but on my wordpress site - no go. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1608231 Look at the javascript console (on Chrome, CTRL+SHIFT+J) - are there any errors?

Comment: First of all, your site has a very old version of jQuery included, you should update it to 1.7+.  Second, only include one form, it will not work with multiple forms.  If you want multiple forms, you'll need to reference the forms by ID or class, like `$('form.className').submit`

Comment: got it to work. so to add more options i would just add more "else ifs"?

Comment: @user1608231 Yes, or you can write a function to handle it.  You should create a follow up question if you have more concerns, comments aren't really meant for this kind of back and forth.