# javascript text field to popup

Tags: javascript, html, forms

asked the original question here:
[Javascript - text field submits to a popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015324/javascript-text-field-submits-to-a-popup-window)

Mash was kind enough to help and answer.

I'm having a strange issue where on the  Home page the code is NOT working - goes into the alert each time. but on other pages - it seems to be working properly.

to test use the code: 120663A

Scroll down and enter the lot number above

Any suggestions/help would be *very* welcome?

thanks
joey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you keep `text-transform: uppercase` in both page. when you type **120663a**, $('input[type=text]').val() only show **120663a**.

That's why `if ($('input[type=text]').val() == "120663a") {`  in http://freshomega.com/w/tester  works and

`if ($('input[type=text]').val() == "120663A") {` in http://freshomega.com/w/ does not work.
I hope this will help.

You can test **120663A** in both page, the result will be reverse.

To solve this, 
I will do the input text to change upper case in both pages for consistency using toUpperCase() function or change both to lower case.

For example,

```
if ($('input[type=text]').val().toUpperCase() == "120663A") {
    window.open("http://freshomega.com/w/files/120663A.pdf");
```

I hope this would help.

Comment: Thanks Swemon - this is my effort to do validation - what is the right way to handle it? I assumed text-transform would ensure that no matter how a user enters the data - the form would process it properly if the numbers/characters were correct..

How would you handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Actually both of your websites work but you are not handling capitalization. In http://freshomega.com/w/ your code says:

```
if ($('input[type=text]').val() == "120663A") {
```

and then in http://freshomega.com/w/tester your code says:

```
if ($('input[type=text]').val() == "120663a") {
```

See the difference? If you straight up type "120663a" into the first one, it's not going to work because it is looking for the capital A. Maybe you can make it disregard case altogether with a .toLowerCase() or .toUpperCase()? Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks AUG - can you show me an example of how to use .tolowercase or vice versa?

Comment: And would it make sense to use one over the other or both? this is my attempt at validating a users input :)

Comment: It doesn't matter which one you use because either way you're just doing it so capitalization isn't a factor. It's a string method so you'd simply be calling it similarly like how you call the val() method:

`if ($('input[type=text]').val().toLowerCase() == "120663a") {`

OR

`if ($('input[type=text]').val().toUpperCase() == "120663A") {`

Actually I completely forgot but there is also an [IgnoreCase function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_ignorecase.asp) that you could consider using so it isn't even an issue. Hope this helps.